# HTTPS Redirect for Wordpress and an independent folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I'm getting crazy with a https redirect problem.

I just switched to https on my little website https://handletteringlernen.de.
I did this by changing the base and home URL of Wordpress to https. After that I changed all the URLs and everything is working fine now. I did not add anything to the .htaccess.

Now I have a folder where the user can use a little tool: http://handletteringlernen.de/generator/
This folder is not part of the wordpress installation, so there is no redirect to https.

When I add

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

to my root .htaccess I have to many redirects. It also does not work, when I place an extra .htaccess in that special folder (/generator/).

Doing a specific 301 redirect from /generator/ to https://handletteringlernen.de/generator/ makes no sense (endless redirects).

I'm stuck - what's the way to do it? Having wordpress and other folders forced to use https?! Without getting the "too many redirects" warning.

EDIT: 
My root .htaccess looks like that now:

```
`#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /the-ultimate-handlettering-alphabet/ 
https://handletteringlernen.de/das-ultimative-handlettering-alphabet/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/generator(\/.*)?$

# Deflate Compression by FileType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# Ablaufzeiten festlegen
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/x-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 4 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/htm "access plus 4 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>

# Protect wp-login.php
<Files wp-login.php>
  AuthName "Protected Admin-Area"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /var/www/web203/html/handletteringlernen/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Files>`
```

My hoster told me they are using some kind of SSL-Proxy. Maybe that causes problems?!

Comment: Why not excluding the generator path for https? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/generator(\/.*)?$

Comment: Excluding? Why should I do this? I want the generator to be on https, too. And the non-https version should be redirected to it.

Comment: Sorry now I understand, what you want... did I understand correct that you do not use .htaccess at all at the moment, but if you add something you end up in a loop (to many redirects)? If so, why not putting the .htaccess file in the generator  folder but with this condition: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC] and %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/generator(\/.*)?$ => so only if https is not already on and we are on /generator folder. If RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [NC] do not work try RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !=on [NC]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I put in your code, I get redirected to the homepage when I visit /generator/.
I also looked up some mod_rewrite tutorials but I can't get it working.
Is there a way to redirect one specific URL to another? That way I could just redirect `http://handletteringlernen.de/generator/` to `https://handletteringlernen.de/generator/`

Answer (score 1):

This is the content of the .htaccess that you can put in your /generator folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?generator(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/generator%1 [R=301,L]
```

You may have to replace `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]` with

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !=on [NC]`

If it don't work you may have some other configuration problems with your apache server. I tested this positiv on Ubuntu 16.04.03 Server with Apache 2.4.27.

EDIT:
because of the SSL-PROXY the server do not know any thing about SSL, but maybe we get the original Request Schema. So instate of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]` try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !=https [NC]`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. But its still not working. I tested both versions, but it still says too many redirects. Although I deleted my cache and cookies.

Comment: I assume that you have some rewrite rule in your root folder or in your apache configure that interfere her, most likely the one that you use with Wordpress. If so exclude the /generator path there: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/generator(\/.*)?$

Comment: Still the same problem. :( I added the content of my root .htaccess to the question.

Comment: You places it wrong. should go somewhere before RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: OK ... I see that you add also the information that you have a SSL-Proxy. This could be of course the reason, because we redirection to the https site... but on the Server itself think there is no SSL so we redirect again, and again, and again.

Comment: Okay, I will contact the support again in order to ask for a solution. If there's none I will move to another hoster ...

Thanks again for taking the time to answer my questions!

Comment: Did %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !=https [NC] also not wotk for you?

Comment: That did not work, too. I'm still talking to the hoster. I will post here, when something changes.

Comment: Hey, it's now working with:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`